# Howto load a smaller version of UImage directly from a file in ios?

Tags: ios, uiimage

When I open large images in an UIImageView (above 2000x3000), my app crashes because of memory consumption, so the idea is to scale the image. So far I have only seen code to load the large image, then draw it in a smaller context, which still needs the memory for the large file.

Is there some way to draw into the context directly from a file or to create an UIImage from file that has the right dimensions?

What I want is to show the content of lets say a jpeg-file with 2000x3000 pixels in lets say a UIImageView with 500x750 pixels. And that without using up too much memory because there are multiple images to be shown.

Any help/ideas are welcome!

Comment: Why so big when the largest iOS device has a resolution of 1024x768?

Comment: there are tons of answers to this in SO. look for a thread safe solution. @elvis' answer is not thread safe b/c is uses `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` which must be called on the main thread. The context should be created with `CGBitmapContextCreate()` instead. Search away, you'll find good answers here.

Comment: The images can be opened also in large size and with zooming, but I need a solution for the preview dialog. I will look for a threadsafe solution, but doesn't that still load the initial image in large size consuming a lot of memory?

Comment: If you need to load large images, there's no way around it. Yes they will take memory. Your goal is to process them in the background as efficiently as possible and release the memory. A good example is processing pics taken with the iPhone camera.

Answer (score 0):

I want an image with height and width 48px, so if the image is different from that size I just resize the image to that size:

```
#define kAppIconHeight 48

// Set appIcon and clear temporary data/image
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];

if (image.size.width != kAppIconHeight && image.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
{
    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    self.appRecord.appIcon = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
else
{
    self.appRecord.appIcon = image;
}

self.activeDownload = nil;
[image release];
```

Comment: this works but is not thread safe and must be called on the main thread. that means UI will be blocked while scaling images, not a great user experience, esp if processing lots of images at once.

Comment: No, you cannot. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` *must* be on the main thread. It cannot be on a background thread no matter what method you use to dispatch operations.

Comment: to be clear, what I mean by "not thread safe" is that this method of scaling cannot be done on a background thread which is typically where you want to do your scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the annotation, I'm going to check that. (=